# parseInt does not work as expected

Tags: javascript

The answer may be obvious but I don't see

I have a JavaScript object virtualTable. I write :

```
parseInt(virtualTable["resource_" + resourceId])
```

it returns `NaN`

I check `virtualTable["resource_" + resourceId]` with an alert and the answer is "690"

If I alert `parseInt("690")` it works fine and returns 690

What is wrong then?

the whole code :

```
if(!virtualTable.hasOwnProperty("resource_" + resourceId)) {
    virtualTable["resource_" + resourceId] = "\"" + minutesToFill + "\"";
}

var timeForTarget = (target.end.getTime() - target.start.getTime()) / 60000;
var timeInVirtualTable;
var tooltipInTarget

if(virtualTable["resource_" + resourceId].indexOf("_") == -1) {
    timeInVirtualTable = parseInt(virtualTable["resource_" + resourceId]);
    tooltipInTarget = "";
} else {
    timeInVirtualTable = parseInt(virtualTable["resource_" + resourceId].substring(0, virtualTable["resource_" + resourceId].indexOf("_")));
    tooltipInTarget = virtualTable["resource_" + resourceId].substring(virtualTable["resource_" + resourceId].indexOf("_"));
}
```

Comment: Please create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) which reproduces the problem and we'll debug it for you.

Comment: So, when you do `alert(virtualTable["resource_" + resourceId])`, it gives you `"690"`, or `690` (without the quotes)? If it's the former, there's your problem - `"690"` is not a number.

Comment: Please add more of your code, can you arrange a jsfiddle example that reproduces it? There can be many reasons

Comment: Whats the virtualTable["resource_" + resourceId] value?

Comment: @kkkkk `I check virtualTable["resource_" + resourceId] with an alert.. the answer is : "690"`

Comment: @newFurniturey : sure it is not a number, it is a string : "690" and I want to parseInt so I can have a number

Comment: Show us where you make that `parseInt` call please.

Comment: The only way I managed to get a NaN is via an undefined value... http://jsfiddle.net/G8vJn/

Comment: To expand on @newfurniturey's comment, if the alert says `"690"` then the value is actually `"\"690\""`

Comment: I dont know how to use this jsfiddle

Comment: @user1689607: `parseInt(new String('690'), 10)` is 690.

Comment: Can you please edit the post showing us the full code where you call `parseInt`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Yeah, I just noticed that.

Comment: @EranMedan Try adding `alert(parseInt("\"690\""));` to your list - it will also give `NaN`.

Comment: @newfurniturey : it doesn't matter if it's in quotes or not, that's the point of parseInt.  His problem is either something with (escaped) quotes as Tom mentioned, or else maybe he's got this in a loop and there's an undefined index

Comment: @David : concerning the typeOf it says  : string

Comment: @mlwacosmos: What does `alert(virtualTable["resource_" + resourceId].length)` say?

Comment: @newfurniturey good point, please make this an answer...

Comment: @CrayonViolent - I beg to differ. If the string was `"690"` instead of simply `690` then `parseInt` would return `NaN`. In either case `parseInt(eval(virtualTable["resource_" + resourceId]))` would solve the problem (for a dirty solution which the rest of the community would frown upon).

Comment: @AaditMShah: Replace the `eval` with `JSON.parse` and you're good.

Comment: If there are actual quote characters in the string, then whatever is storing the numeric string in the first place needs to be fixed.

Comment: @RocketHazmat - That's cool, but I don't understand - why and how does `JSON.parse` work in this case?

Comment: -1 Please do not say "does not work" - even in titles. Instead, specify what *doesn't* occur or *does* occur that is unexpected.

Comment: @AaditMShah I think there is some confusion here.  Right, if the quotes were PART of the string, as in `someString = '"690"'` then yes that would return NaN because the quotes are part of the value of the string.  Vs. `someString = "690"` this is fine and will work

Comment: @CrayonViolent - I thought we already had that established.

Comment: @AaditMShah: It might not be "valid" JSON, but `"690"` still seems to count as JSON.  It's just a single value instead of an array or object.

Comment: @mlwacosmos would you please unselect my answer as the accepted one? they other answer is better, and deserves it more, and I can't delete my answer as long as it's the accepted one. thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Per your statement,

> I check virtualTable["resource_" + resourceId] with an alert and the
>   answer is "690"

I'm assuming that the value inside `virtualTable["resource_" + resourceId]` is literally `"690"`, including the quotes. Because of this, it's `NaN`, or, not-a-number (due to the leading double-quote).

If this will be common input, you can strip the double-quotes from your value before (or during) the call to parseInt using `replace()`:

```
var value = virtualTable["resource_" + resourceId].replace(/"/g, '');
var number = parseInt(value);
```

or:

```
var number = parseInt(virtualTable["resource_" + resourceId].replace(/"/g, ''));
```

**EDIT** (`parseInt()`'s base):
Building on a comment, you should also remember to always specify the numeric-base to parse the input to. In your case, you want base-10 (or "decimal"). This is specified as the second parameter to `parseInt()`:

```
var number = parseInt(value, 10);
```

or

```
var number = parseInt(virtualTable["resource_" + resourceId].replace(/"/g, ''), 10);
```

Comment: I guess you nailed it. But don't forget to pass the base to `parseInt`!